# Calculating speedup of this parallel program

Tags: parallel-computing

I have a sequential program that has a cost of
$(\sum_{n=1}^{N} Ti )$  Where Ti is the load time of the i-th element, so if consider $Tm = max({Ti}) $ i can approximate the sequential cost as $N*Tm$ that has a linear cost.

Let's suppose that i have c cores and i decide to parallelize this program, i can divide the loading of these items among c cores so i have (At most)

$(\sum_{n=1}^{N/C} Ti ) \leq Tm \cdot N/C$

So in brief:

Sequential (approx.) cost: $N*Tm$

Parallel(approx.) cost: $[N/c]*Tm$

How can i calculate the speedup? what about the efficiency?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why not just divide these values?

Comment: I was asking if that is right.

Comment: What is right? Do you want to compare these approximations? Sure, you can go and divide them (since this is literally what you want to compute). Do you want to estimate the actual speedup? Then no. Dividing one upper bound on another in general gives you nothing. In this case, assume that one element takes much more time than others. Then parallelization doesn't give any speedup.

Comment: Could you mention what do you mean by "load"? Is something being read from some permanent storage?

Comment: Yes @ajit the program will import some informations inside an array from a  permanent storage.

Comment: So there is absolutely nothing that can be parallelized here !

Comment: If by "sequential" you mean reads from a sequential device, every thread will have to wait for its turn. No speedup. But if the device allows direct access reads performed concurrently, the total load time will probably be much longer, due to the device controller striving to service the simultaneous requests. Speeddown.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of application you mention seems to be I/O bound i.e., application execution time is dominated by I/O time (Ti). In this case using multiple threads is not going to be advantageous as there is only **one connection** between your I/O device (permanent storage) and CPU (having multiple cores). That **one connection** is the bottleneck. You will not observe much of a speed-up as you increase the number of threads. There may be slight gain as number of threads increase initially, as threads try to saturate and use the **maximum bandwidth** possible for the I/O connection. Gain will also depend on how much time is spend on I/O and how much on processing of read data. Both of them can run in parallel for two different threads. But your question seems to suggest that I/O time (to get data) >> compute time (to process data). Hence there will be limited gain by increasing the number of threads. Instead, try to optimize the I/O. Keep it sequential and read in larger blocks.

Comment: Perfect, that was the confirm i was waiting for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the algorithm. Some algorithms can be split between processors, some can't. For example to find the maximum of N numbers, you can split into m groups, find the maximum of each group in O (N / m) assuming m cores, and the result is the maximum in your m numbers, taking another O (m) for a total of O (N / m + m), you can probably do better if m is very large compared to N. For small-ish m, the speed up will be a bit less than m.

Other algorithms, the i-th element can only be processed after all previous elements are processed, and you can't get any speedup at all.

The other question is whether your time to process one element is the same if you use m cores. Some processors need to slow down when they get hot, so if you use 16 cores they run slower than with one core. Or you may have one set of RAM chips that cannot supply data to 16 cores at 16 times the speed. For these cases, it's best to measure the speedup.

And there is the problem that your processing resources may be limited. If you have m cores, and want to run multiple applications, one application trying to use all m cores will slow down the others. Does this happen? In these cases, are the results of your code urgent, more urgent than others? If yes, then it may be Ok to slow others down. If not then maybe not. And a speedup of m will be fine, but a speedup of log n won't.

Comment: "you can probably do better if m is very large compared to N": what ?? How would you process 10 numbers with 100 cores ???

Comment: The simple algorithm as written down, will split the data into 10 groups of 1 item, get the maximum of each group in O (1), and then will find the maximum of 10 items. Using 2-4 cores would be more efficient than using 10 or 100.

Comment: What about 100 groups of 0.1 item ?